Unable to change the default version of Python in the virtual environment
I want to create a virtual environment with Python version 3.9. I am using Windows11 operating system. I found various python version in the folder C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python. The python versions are as follows

Now if I want to create a virtual environment following the command python39 -m venv myvenv
I received the error message 'python39' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I also tried another way to create a virtual environment, that did not work either
How can I solve this?
Thank you.


Can you run py, the Python Launcher on Windows? Do you get all your Python installations correctly listed with the command py --list? Can you create a virtual environment with the command py -3.9 -m venv myvenv?

"python39" would mean the version "39", you need to use "python3.9" as command.

py --list returned -V:3.12 *        Python 3.12 (64-bit)
-V:3.9           Python 3.9 (64-bit)
-V:ContinuumAnalytics/Anaconda39-64 Anaconda 2022.05

You are using Windows, so you can utilize the Python Launcher which was included in Python 3.3.
Example:
py --list
 -V:3.12          Python 3.12 (64-bit)
 -V:3.11 *        Python 3.11 (64-bit)
 -V:ContinuumAnalytics/Anaconda39-64 Anaconda 2022.10

With this command you can see that I have 3 version of Python installed in the Windows environment. To make a virtual environment using 3.11:
py -3.11 -m venv myvenv
myvenv\Scripts\activate

(myvenv) C:\Users\Andy>python --version
Python 3.11.5

This command would have worked the same way without the -3.11 because 3.11 is my default (it has the asterisk in the --list output)
To utilize a different version of Python you need to change the parameter passed to the command
py -3.12 -m venv myvenv1
myvenv1\Scripts\activate

(myvenv1) C:\Users\Andy>python --version
Python 3.12.3

For your example, you can pass 3.9, because it's in your --list output
